# Custom Aggregation Expression in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a custom aggregation (along with several other standard aggregations).

Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["red", 1, 10], ["red", 2, 20], ["green", 5, 15]],
    columns=["color", "x", "y"]
) 

df2 = (
    df
    .groupby(["color"])
    .agg(amt1=("x", "sum"),
         amt2=("x", "mean"),      
         amt3=("y", "sum"),
         # this does not work...
         amt4= (0.9 * (x.sum() - y.mean()) / x.max()) + 1
        )
)

df2
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: custom aggregation requires an anoymous function ... a ```lambda x: ...```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Expected output is four columns (in addition to the color column that we're grouping by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible directly to use two columns in the custom function with `agg`, you have two choices here. Either use `apply` for this specific custom function and `concat` with `agg` the others, or use index based selection.

```
# option 1
gr = df.groupby(["color"])
df2 = pd.concat([gr.agg(amt1=("x", "sum"), amt2=("x", "mean"), amt3=("y", "sum")), 
                 gr.apply(lambda dfg: (0.9 * (dfg.x.sum() - df.y.mean()) 
                                      / dfg.x.max()) + 1)
                   .rename('amt4')],
                axis=1 )

# option 2
df2 = (df.groupby(["color"])
         .aggregate(amt1=("x", "sum"), amt2=("x", "mean"), amt3=("y", "sum"),
                    amt4= ('x', lambda x: (0.9 * (x.sum() - df.loc[x.index, 'y'].mean()) 
                                          / x.max()) + 1))
      )
```

both give the same result as long as the index are unique in df

to use option 2 in the new version need regular function [bug description](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30536)

```
def named_lambda(x):
     return (0.9 * (x.sum() - df.loc[x.index, 'y'].mean()) / x.max()) + 1

df2 = (df.groupby(["color"])
         .aggregate(amt1=("x", "sum"), amt2=("x", "mean"), amt3=("y", "sum"),
                    amt4= ('x', named_lambda))
)
```

Comment: Option 2 is giving me an error:  KeyError: "[('x', '<lambda>')] not in index".  Running Pandas 0.25.3 in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Option 1 does work, but hoping option 2 can work somehow.  Are you able to get option 2 working in your environment?

Comment: @RedTailedHawk I've the same bug and resolve it by regular function, hope it help you

Comment: @BearBrown interesting that defining the function works but not the lambda, thanks for editing though

Comment: Guess it's a Python bug, but at least there's a workaround.  Thanks guys!!